# How do I access NSApplicationDelegate from XCUIApplication in my UI tests

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, cocoa, xcode-ui-testing

I need to access some values in the app delegate to modify (and test) updates process with Sparkle. So the question is, how do I access NSApplicationDelegate from XCUIApplication in my UI tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:**
You can´t access you `AppDelegate` file from your UITest project.

**Long answer:**
As stated by Oletha in [their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084480/how-to-access-the-app-delegate-from-a-ui-test/38086038#38086038):

> Xcode UI testing is designed such that the test code can only see what a user can see, so no objects from the application under test can be used or inspected in the test code. This is also why the views on the screen are represented as XCUIElement objects instead of UIView descendants.
>
> The UI tests run in a separate executable from the application under test.

Comment: Please don't reject legitimate edits that add proper attribution to your answer.

Comment: @BradLarson, I don´t really remember when I rejected that edit but when I did I sure had my reasons. It´s still my answer and of course I´m always open for improvements for my answers and will not reject all edits.